# "You and ME" Versus "YOU and I"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is correct, “you and I” or “you and me”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/which-is-correct-you-and-i-or-you-and-me)
>   [“Me and my wife” or “my wife and me”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48397/me-and-my-wife-or-my-wife-and-me)

Is this sentence correct "All I need is you and I " ?? since "All I need is I" seems not proper here whereas "All I need is you" does.

Comment: *All I need is me*, though grammatical, is a very odd thing to say.  You might want to rephrase, though it's difficult to say without context.

Comment: I've been pondering upon a lyrics of a song named "without you" by Usher,I hope you've heard it already,but anyways,there is a part of sentence where "All I Need is you and I, without you" is used .so,is this  sentence correct here??

Comment: When I said 'poets might be drawn' this kind of usage, I didn't have Usher in mind...

Comment: lol..alright..thanks a lot anyways...I'll keep it in mind regarding the usage of You and I.

Comment: Anything goes with poetry and lyrics.

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMAR: Are you asking in this case: "All I need is you and I/me happily married together."?

Comment: @Shyam No,I was just wondering about the lyrics where "All I need is you and I, without you" is used.Well,seeing your example it has made me curious to know what  correct word should be placed in here.

Comment: @Mitch mhm..I see...hehe,which is why its fun,I guess.

Comment: @Shyam I think it should be "me" instead of I  as in "All I need, is you and me happily married together".?

Comment: @FumbleFingers yeah true.

Comment: 'I' is correct in that sentence. "All I need is you and I happily married together."

Comment: Now I am once again confused !

Comment: @Shyam I searched many threads similar to mine and I found that with this type of sentences ,we always should remove the "You and" Part and see if the sentence sounds good or normal or not ridiculous.Like here,"All I need is me happily married together" which sounds nice as when compared to "All I need is I happily married together" SO,the correct sentence would be "All I need is you and me happily married together"

Comment: I don't think is is a duplicate. The one question http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1047/13812 deals with objects, whereas the question here is about predicate nominatives. The other question http://english.stackexchange.com/q/48397/13812 deals with pronoun order, whereas that really doesn't have much to do with this question.

Comment: @SANTOSHKUMAR: It is not about sounding good, the question is if we need a subject or object. Consider: "All I need is he and she happily married together." Will 'him or her' fit here? No. So we need a subject, which is "I".

Comment: okay..so,what will fit here anyway??

Comment: "All I need is you and I happily married together" :)

Comment: "All I need is for you and I to be happily married."

Answer (score 0):

Although it's correct, as Tim has pointed out, it's also very unnatural.  Poets might be drawn to it because it's a playful repetition which gets us to focus on the meaning.

When you use *I*, you're usually employing it in the nominative case because *I* is the subject of the sentence:

> I kicked the ball
>
> I walked to the shops
>
> I am a keen cook

but when you use *me* you're generally using it in the accusative case because *I* is now the object of the sentence:

> The star amazed me
>
> Everything seems fine to me
>
> Mary kicked me in the leg

Comment: oh thank you Jamie ,you clarified all my doubts :)

Comment: Trouble is, there's no evidence that "nominative" and "accusative" are meaningful categories in English.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is incorrect. You can think of *is* as a sort of equal sign, where you can put the subject as a predicate nominative and vice-versa and the sentence will be correct. Breaking it down, then, the subject, predicate, and predicate nominative are:

> All I need is you and me.
>   all | is / you and I
>   you and I | is / all *(reversed subject/predicate nominative)*

It should be (you could substitute *we* for *you and I*, if that helps to understand a bit better):

> All I need are you and I.
>   all | are / you and I
>   you and I / are | all *(reversed subject/predicate nominative)*

With a single nominative, it should read:

> All I need am I.
>   all | am / I
>   I | am / all *(reversed subject/predicate nominative)*

Comment: "Is" does not just function as an equal sign, and you can't just reverse the word order and get another valid sentence. Consider that "I am he" is correct, but *"He am I" is wrong, and "It is they" is correct, but *"they is it" is wrong. The form of "to be" agrees only with the noun phrase that acts as a subject; in this case, that is "all I need", and the grammatical number of "you and me/I" is irrelevant.